Adding up the values ​from the input array in the table then accumulating the amount of data
I tried adding up the good and bad values, if the check total was the same as the product total, then the submit button could be accessed, but the results did not appear to retrieve data on the number of each row. When the check amount and total amount are the same, the button can be submitted


var tot = 0;
$('.calculation-table tbody tr td input').on('input', function() {
    var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 

    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // get tr which contains the input
    var tot = 0; // variable to sore sum
    $('input', $tr).each(function() { // iterate over inputs
      tot += Number($(this).val()) || 0; // parse and add value, if NaN then add 0
    });

    if(tot == col1){
        $('td:last', $tr).prev().text(tot).css('color', 'green');
    }else{
        $('td:last', $tr).prev().text(tot).css('color', 'red');
    }

    enableDIsableSubmit();
  }).trigger('input'); 

  function enableDIsableSubmit() {
      let rowCount = $("table > tbody > tr").length;
      let check = $("table tbody tr").find("td:last:contains(2)").length;
      $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', (rowCount != check || (check == 0 || rowCount == 0)));
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table class="calculation-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="paysilp-table-border">
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;">Total</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;" class="text-center">Good</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;" class="text-center">No Good</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;" class="text-center">Check</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="paysilp-table-borders">
      <tr>
        <td>45</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality1[]" value="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality2[]" value="25"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="check-qty"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality1[]" value="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality2[]" value="10"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="check-qty"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality1[]" value="15"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality2[]" value="0"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="check-qty"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>




As I understood, you need to update each row's check field value by summing up all the input box values in each row.
if the check value of each row is the same as the first td value of each row you want to update the color of the check value to either green or red.
Also if all row's first td values are equal to their corresponding check values then you want to enable the button.
You can simplify your code like below:
Working snippet:


$(function() {
  checkAndUpdateTable();
  $('.calculation-table tbody tr input').keyup(function() {
    checkAndUpdateTable();
  });

});

function checkAndUpdateTable() {
  $('.calculation-table tbody tr').each(function() {
    let total = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    let qty = 0;
    $('input', $(this)).each(function() {
      qty += Number($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $(this).find('td:last').text(qty).css('color', (qty == total) ? 'green' : 'red');

  });
  enableDIsableSubmit();
}

function enableDIsableSubmit() {
  let finalTotal = 0;
  $(".calculation-table > tbody > tr").find("td:first").each(function() {
    finalTotal += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
  });  
  
  let finalCheck = 0;
  $(".calculation-table > tbody > tr").find("td:last").each(function() {
    finalCheck += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
  });  
  
  $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', (finalTotal != finalCheck || (finalCheck == 0 || finalTotal == 0)));
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table class="calculation-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="paysilp-table-border">
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;">Total</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;" class="text-center">Good</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;" class="text-center">No Good</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:15%;" class="text-center">Check</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="paysilp-table-borders">
      <tr>
        <td>45</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality1[]" value="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality2[]" value="25"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="check-qty"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality1[]" value="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality2[]" value="10"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="check-qty"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality1[]" value="15"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quality2[]" value="0"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="check-qty"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>



